# Find the K-th number with a certain property using Digit DP and Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I recently encountered a problem which asks you to find the K-th number which satisfies a certain property. For example:

> Find the K-th number whose sum of digits equals 60.

While I was reading about **Digit Dynamic Programming**, I learned that we could do this "using binary search and a counting function".

### What I tried

I wrote a counting function `F(N)` using Digit DP which, given a number N, counts all numbers in the range `[1, N]` having sum of digits equal to `60`. Now, if I have two numbers X and Y such that `X < Y`, then `F(X) <= F(Y)`. I used this observation to write a binary search method, which calculates two values, namely the lower bound and the upper bound.

`Lower Bound: the last number for which F(N) < K`

`Upper Bound: the last number for which F(N) <= K`

Then I iterated from Lower Bound to Upper Bound to find the answer.

### My Question

What I want to know is, is this method correct?

- If no, how do we solve this problem?
- If yes, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is possible another way like you can find what is minimum digit required to get sum equals to desired sum that you can generalize for desired sum more than 0 :
    
    if sum is even
      minimum_number_of_digit=sum/9
    else
      minimum_number_of_digit=(sum/9)+1

Now you have minimum number of digits.You can find  Kth number after solving problem "Counting numbers of digit X whose sum is equal to desired sum" and Here X >= Minimum number of digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting point of your answer seems to be correct if you need to use digit dp and binary search only. But I cant understand what the `upperbound` and `lowerbound` are used for or are they even required.

Here's how i would do the question after making function `F()`-

```
binary_search(int start,int end,int k){
    int mid=(start+end)/2;

    //mid is answer only if F(mid) has exactly k numbers and F(mid-1) has k-1 numbers
    if(F(mid)==k&&F(mid-1)==k-1) return mid;

    //if F(mid) has less than k numbers we need to check for greater numbers for answer
    else if(F(mid)<k) return binary_search(mid+1,end,k);

    //finally if F(mid) has more than or equal to k numbers we check smaller numbers for answer
    else return binary_search(start,mid-1,k);
}
```

(Trivial suggestion) When you make function `F(N)` you should make it such that it calculates and stores value of `F(x)` where `x` belongs to range `[1,N]`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the part where I got stuck! :)